# Who is winning?

Tags: online-chess

I was white

FEN

> 4rrk1/1ppq1pp1/p1n4p/7P/P2PP3/P4Q2/4N3/R1B1K2R b Q - 0 1

[image]

Comment: Does white still have castling rights? The FEN string seems to indicate that this is not the case. Also, I might add that it doesn't have to be the case that one side is winning by force here.

Comment: right side rook had moved but not the left one.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the FEN to display this

Comment: I'm winning here - if I play you I win with both colors :) - this is still playable position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take Black. While the attack is not winning, its quite annoying to stop. White has to make some computer moves to defend, starting from Qd3.

According to engine it’s just little better for black, but it’s not simple to play White! Black wins by force if White doesn’t respond perfectly. Don’t forget Black can always go into a good endgame with enough pawns for compensation. The d4 and e4 are going to fall, the other pawns might also fall as well.

The computer gives:

[image]

Comment: My own Smallfish app @Shad

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to have an engine answer such questions.
If it's white to move then personally I think with accurate play white is winning. I would play Bb2 and prepare to castle long, playing e5 if black plays f5.

Comment: Black to move in FEN

Comment: Then I am pretty sure black is borderline winning here, white's position looks extremely busted after Nxd4.